# Amazon Gateway - access original request body in integration response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Good day everyone, my problem related with Amazon Gateway API. I have the following case:

> 1. Response received from 3rd party service and contains no query params (all necessary data stored in body)
> 2. I'am able to modify body and pass it to target URL via Integration Request
> 3. Integration Request finished, i receive some data from target endpoint
> 4. Now i need to create Integration Response, based on original data (received in 1.) and data, received from target endpoint.

Problem appears at stage 4. I can't find a way to access original body here (**$input.body** contains response from target endpoint, there is no original data).

I also tried to store necessary data in scope variables (**$input/$context)**, but it seems like AWS Gateway allows only to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you cannot access the $input.body in the integration response mapping. We will consider supporting this in the future.

Comment: Do you know if this ever was implemented? I am trying to do this now. Thanks!

Comment: Not yet, but people have found hacks to get around the limitation [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482410/563812](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482410/563812)