# AWS API Gateway: Use Mock Integration to echo response body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use the Mock integration to just "echo" back me the JSON body that I sent. However, I just can't get it to work. I can return any arbitrary JSON body from my "POST - Integration Response", but the request JSON is never found via `$input.json('$')`. I have been able to successfully echo back any query parameters.

My API has a single "/" path and a single method defined (POST). The exported yaml is [here](https://gist.github.com/amitsaha/a15b72d3aac9faac19390ade38c85da6) .

Any idea as to what may be going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported. In the mapping template for "Integration Response", `$input` represents the payload received from the integration response (which is empty in the case of a `MOCK` integration.

Comment: Ah, wait. How can I access the input query parameters then?

Comment: I would like to know as well if this is possible now.

Comment: Query params and headers pass as usual for me (using method request passthrough template). but the body is always {} from Mock.

Comment: not sure if it is "supported" but there is a way to do this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 34):

I've found this to actually be possible, although a little hacky. 
First, in the integration request mapping template you store the body in a path parameter.

```
#set($context.requestOverride.path.body = $input.body)
{
  "statusCode": 200,
}
```

Then in the integration response mapping template you fetch it back and return it.

```
#set($body = $context.requestOverride.path.body)
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": $body,
}
```

This seems to even work well with larger payloads.

Comment: This work for me, also to add to the, if you want to parse body and extract it we can use `"someVar": $util.parseJson($body).someVar,`

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a lambda function for echoing purposing, something like that:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return event;
};
```