# Is it possible to access the original request body in a response body mapping template in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Using API Gateway, I am trying to define a POST end point that accepts application/json to do the following:

1. Trigger a Lambda asynchronously
2. Respond with a JSON payload composed of elements from the request body

I have #1 working. I think it's by the book.

It's #2 I'm getting tripped up on. It looks like I don't have access to the request body in the context of the response mapping template. I have access to the original query params with $input.params but I cannot find any property that will give me the original request body, and I need it to get the data that I want to respond with. It's either that or I need to figure out how to get the asynchronous launch of a Lambda to somehow provide the original request body.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

My goal is to ensure that my API responds as fast as possible without incurring a cold start of a Lambda to respond AND simultaneously triggering an asynchronous workflow by starting a Lambda. I'd also be willing to integrate with SNS instead of Lambda directly and have Lambda subscribe to the topic but I don't know if that will get me access to the data I need in the response mapping template.

Comment: have you tried something like this `{
    "name" : "$input.params('name')",
    "body" : $input.json('$') 
}` or even just `$input.body` directly?

Comment: @NickiKlein $input.params has the original querystring parameters for the request but $input.body is empty because it's coming from an async lambda invocation and I cannot find the original request body in any variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have determined that it is not possible to do what I want to do.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper provided the correct response

Answer (score 6):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482410/3221253:

Save the original request body in the integration mapping template:

```
#set($context.requestOverride.path.body = $input.body)
```

Retrieve it in the integration mapping response:

```
#set($body = $context.requestOverride.path.body)
{
   "statusCode": 200,
   "body": $body,
}
```

You can also access specific attributes:

```
#set($object = $util.parseJson($body))
{
    "id": "$object.id"
}
```

Comment: Can happily confirm that this solution still works.
I strongly advise waiting a minute after deployment as it seems the changes take that long at least

Answer (score 0):

To access the original request directly, you should use a [Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) for Lambda rather than mapping things via a normal integration. You'll be able to access the entire request context, such as headers, path params, etc.

Comment: You mean to access the original request inside a Lambda, correct? That's not what I want. I want to access the original request in the response body mapping template and I want the Lambda fired asynchronously so that I'm not waiting on the Lambda to execute before I send my response back.